# Car-following models considering the friction of the road

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling, optimal-control

I have the next car-following model,

$\ddot{x}_n(t)=\lambda[\dot{x}_{n-1}(t)-\dot{x}_n(t)]$,

but I'm wondering how I can "write" this model based on the friction between the vehicle and the road and the geometric structure of the road.

They could help me with some steps of how I should go concatenating the friction and the geometrical structure of the track, I feel that I should consider the dynamics of the vehicle [Vehicles dynamics](https://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBD24/VT05/lectures/vehicles.pdf)

Comment: You could make $\lambda$ a function of $x_{n-1}(t)-x_n(t)$ and $x_n(t)$ respectively, but without more context it is hard for me to say what that function should be and how accurate it would model the dynamics you try to capture.

Comment: How could you formulate a cost functional that minimizes travel time, taking into account the friction and the geometrical structure of the track?

Comment: That is a whole separate question, which can't be answered in a comment.